# SendGrid - Send mails from customers own domain

Tags: email, dns, sendgrid

I'm working on a product where we use SendGrid.com so send system e-mails to our customers' end users. These e-mails origniate from our own domain - let's call it `ourdomain.example`. This is done by going through SendGrid's authenticated domain flow to set up DNS records to validate the domain.

Several of our customers have asked if we can send the system e-mails from their own domain, e.g. they would like if e-mails sent from the system was sent on behalf of `@customerdomain.example`.

The question is - how do I set this up in SendGrid so that we can deliver DNS settings to the customers?

I really don't want this to be a manual process as we might have hundreds of customers who want to use their own domain. I've tried reaching out to SendGrid support, but they basically keep linking to this page: https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication. This is what we've done for our own domain, but this isn't really a viable solution if we need to handle hundreds of domains from different customers.

Does anyone know if the process can be automated via the SendGrid API? Something like this perhaps:

- The customer creates an account with us (domain: customerdomain.com)
- We call SendGrid's API saying "create domain validation for domain `customerdomain.example`"
- We get back the DNS entries the customer (owner of `customerdomain.example`) needs to enter into their DNS setup
- We start sending e-mails with the From address set to `something@customerdomain.example`

Maybe I'm looking in all the wrong places, but I simply can't figure out how to do this the right way.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: were you able to automate it? if so, i'd be happy if you share

Comment: @Amitk - I've added the chosen solution to the original post. Hope this helps you out :)

Comment: We have been sending emails like this for almost 8 years now and all of a sudden it is starting to give us the same problem.  Even though we validated our domain and a sender there is no possible way we can pre-validate every potential domain on the entire internet.  Our app DEPENDS on this ability.

Comment: @ScottMilella are you experiencing validation issues or simply can't send email via the validated domains? We haven't gotten any feedback regarding the solution not working properly anymore, but I'd be very interested in knowing if this is might be failing. Did you reach out to SendGrid regarding this?

Comment: @InversionDK  Take a look at my new answer, I added it in, in case it might help someone else.  SendGrid stopped allowing us to send email to non authenticated domains.  It used to allow this just fine but seems to have either been tightened up or fixed or?  Something changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a few different approaches, we eventually got this working by using the SendGrid API in the following manner:

1. For each custom domain, authenticate this using the Domains API (https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/domain-authentication/authenticate-a-domain)
   This will give you a domain ID as well as a DNS object containing the CNAME and DKIM values to set for the domain.
   Ask your customer to apply these to the domain's DNS settings.
2. Once the DNS changes have been applied, verify them by calling the Validate method on the domains API: https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/domain-authentication/validate-a-domain-authentication

If the domain was successfully validated, you can then use the domain as a sender domain through SendGrid.

I hope this helps someone else experiencing trouble with this.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding a second answer in case this helps someone.
For years we had no issues sending email from lets call it domain1.  I authenticated domain1 on SendGrid and when we would send email we would replace our email address sender@domain1.com we will call it with whatever the customers email address was and that worked.  Well in the last couple of years we started to see more issues with this and then it was to a point where only a handful of customers were working at all this way; even though it HAD been working that way for YEARS.

My best guess as to why some of our customers are able to send and most of the others can not (especially the FREE email accounts) you ask?  The customers that were still working this way I believe must have had their email domain already authenticated someway via SendGrid.  Weather they have their own app or something?  This is just a guess but there is about 10-15 customers that were still able to send this way even though their email addresses did not match the domain1.com authenticated domain.

I do understand the issue at hand and why it has stopped working.  We authenticated domain1 yet the customers email address might be user@gmail.com or user@hotmail.com.   This would technically be SPOOFING because the email stamped in the FROM doesn't match the server and there is no SPF in place for the customers email domain.  Incidentally @gmail and @hotmail domains now FAIL 100% of the time now if we try the way we WERE doing it.  That is how I spotted the issue I created a test account and noticed the emails were not going out or rather the emails that were not going out where the ones were the customers email address gets stamped over the FROM.  So I turned on debug and noticed the SendGrid errors stating that the email user@gmail.com is not an Authenticated Email address (language might be slightly off).  I did go back into our history and check and about a year or maybe a year and a half ago is when this issue first started to get more prevalent.  I assume SendGrid probably never intended this method to work in the first place and maybe they now have tightened this up?  This is just a guess.  This app I am working on was setup this way before from the beginning and was originally written by someone else.

TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE this is what I did.  I made it where our FROM email address is always no-reply@domain1.com.  I then take the customers email address and use it as a REPLY TO email address INSTEAD OF the FROM email address.  By doing this we are now in compliance because we are sending from domain1.

Yet if an email goes to a customer and they hit reply now the reply will at least go to the customers email address instead of the no-reply email address.
Someone can mess this up if they manually CHANGE the reply to I suppose.  It was the only way I could figure out to solve the issue without having to Authenticate EVERY CUSTOMERS email domain.

I will probably later on setup some code to where we CAN flip a Boolean value on a table to allow customers to send with their own email address (providing they can put in the SendGrid DNS Info).  I am still debating on if that would be a benefit or not.

For now it works 100% of the time now with the way I have it setup with sending FROM domain1 and using the customers email address as a REPLY TO.

If anyone has any comments or questions about this I will be happy to answer as best as I can.  It took me a long time to figure out WHY this was happening and it looked Random at first because of the fact some domains were sending, even though I think based on what I understand that SHOULDN'T work at ALL anymore, if it ever should have worked to being with.