# Sending Emails through SendGrid from their own domains

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

According to the recent changes as enforced by the Gmail and Yahoo, SendGrid has asked its users to comply with the email authentication protocols like DKIM, SPF, DMARC as per in the blog post:

https://sendgrid.com/en-us/blog/new-sending-requirements-for-gmail-yahoo

And in our project, every user has their own domain, and they want to send the email to their customers through their own domain. So to adhere the domain authentication for multiple domains in our SendGrid, I found across this stackoverflow answer:

[SendGrid - Send mails from customers own domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74097703/sendgrid-send-mails-from-customers-own-domain)

And I just want to clarify some things like, is there a limit to add only 3000 subuser domains in the SendGrid? And how authenticating the domains from sub user is different from normal domain authentication i.e. without the subusers?